# How to convert HTML codes in JSON file to characters in Ionic 3

Tags: html, ionic-framework, encoding, ionic3, pipe

I'm trying to read in some JSON files to HTML but the HTML characters are displaying as codes. I've tried using `[innerHTML]="{{item.detail}}"` but its not working, any help please?

Code sample:

```
            <ion-row *ngFor="let item of items; index as i;">
              <span class="txt">{{item.topic}}</span><br>
              <span class="txt">{{item.excerp}}</span><br>
              <ion-col class="q">[innerHTML] = "{{item.detail}}"<br>
```

Comment: Can you please reduce your code to a [mre] and provide it for others to recreate your issue? Please also review [ask] and edit your question to conform to the guidance therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innerHTML is a directive

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of items; index as i;">
              <span class="txt">{{item.topic}}</span><br>
              <span class="txt">{{item.excerp}}</span><br>
              <ion-col class="q" [innerHTML] = "item.detail"></ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

or

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let item of items; index as i;">
              <span class="txt">{{item.topic}}</span><br>
              <span class="txt">{{item.excerp}}</span><br>
              <ion-col class="q" innerHTML = "{{item.detail}}"></ioncol>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. the first reply fixed it. Its working now.